# no module named 'project' in gunicorn using Django 1.8 & python 3.4

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn

I've deployed with ansible a project using Django 1.8 and python3.4 in a virtualenv folder. For my projects including settings and wsgi in a config folder it works, the deployment is fine and it works. For my project where settings and wsgi are in the project root directory, it doesn't.

Nginx works fine. It's gunicorn with supervisor that scratch with a `no module named 'project'` issue.

here is the layout of my project:

`├── gunicorn.conf.py
├── gunicorn.log
├── nginx-access.log
├── nginx-error.log
└── project
    ├── contributors.txt
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── rdt_theme
    ├── README.md
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── settings.py
    ├── static
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py`

Supervisor conf.d:

```
[program:gunicorn_rdtfront]
command=/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/bin/gunicorn wsgi -c /opt/www/rdtfront/gunicorn.conf.py
directory=/opt/www/rdtfront/project
user=rdtfront
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=True
stdout_logfile=/opt/www/rdtfront/gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile=/opt/www/rdtfront/gunicorn.log
```

My gunicorn.conf.py:

```
import multiprocessing

bind = "unix:///tmp/rdtfront.sock"
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1

user = 'rdtfront'

logfile = "/opt/www/rdtfront/gunicorn.log"
loglevel = "info"
pidfile = '/tmp/rdtfront.pid'
daemon = False
debug = False
timeout = 300
```

And my wsgi.py:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this issue. Supervisor keeps restarting the project in vain.

Below the error output: 
`[2015-06-26 17:06:06 +0200] [451] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 451)
[2015-06-26 17:06:06 +0200] [452] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 394, in urlconf_module
    return self._urlconf_module
AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'`

`During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/opt/www/rdtfront/project/wsgi.py", line 9, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/debug_toolbar/apps.py", line 15, in ready
    dt_settings.patch_all()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 232, in patch_all
    patch_root_urlconf()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 220, in patch_root_urlconf
    reverse('djdt:render_panel')
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 550, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 352, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 285, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 402, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 396, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named 'project'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 394, in urlconf_module
    return self._urlconf_module
AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'`

`During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/opt/www/rdtfront/project/wsgi.py", line 9, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/debug_toolbar/apps.py", line 15, in ready
    dt_settings.patch_all()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 232, in patch_all
    patch_root_urlconf()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 220, in patch_root_urlconf
    reverse('djdt:render_panel')
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 550, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 352, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 285, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 402, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 396, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named 'project'
[2015-06-26 17:06:06 +0200] [452] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 452)
/opt/.virtualenvs/rdtfront/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py:321: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.`

Comment: Having a very similar issue, same versions.  Did you ever get a resolution?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Does it work for you now? Yes it works for me. You have to check all your paths. I can't remember exactly which one was incorrect. It took me a while to understand what's going on behind the hood.